# How to use EGit to create an Eclipse project in the root folder of a git repo

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I'm new to git, so I'm likely doing something basically wrong.

Using latest Kepler.

We have a mostly empty git repo. I have managed to create a "readme.md" file at the root of the repo. Someone else also put a ".project" file at the root of the repo. We'll call that root project "projroot".

I cloned the repo to "c:/Users//git/projroot

I now need to create some subfolders off of the root which are also standalone Eclipse projects. I don't understand what the next step would be. I tried creating a Maven project in my workspace. Would I then "share" it? I tried doing this, but it says the following:

```
Can not move project <newproject> to target location C:\Users\<myid>\git\<projroot>\<newproject>,
as this location overlaps with location C:\Users\<myid>\git\<projroot>, which contains a
.project file
```

I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Am I having this problem because we've mistakenly created a "top-level" repo that we intended to contain all of our related projects?

Comment: I guess it's clear that we simply can't put a ".project" file at the root if we intend for that repo to contain other projects.